# Не получается соединиться с сервером БД PostgreSQL

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, psql

Открываю терминал и запускаю сервер:

```
j_ch@playground:~/project/bin$ ./postgres -D ~/project/DemoDb
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-09-22 16:03:02 +05
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Вроде бы успешно.

Далее открываю другой терминал и пытаюсь соединиться с сервером БД:

```
j_ch@playground:~$ psql postgres
psql: could not connect to server: Нет такого файла или каталога
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Выдает ошибку - как справиться с ней?
Если в последнем терминале ввести :

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Ответом будет:

```
Failed to start postgresql.service: Unit postgresql.service not found
```

PostgreSQL версии 9.6(git clone https://github.com/[my fork on github]/postgres и собрано). PSQL автоматом не появился, пришлось отдельно устанавливать psql-client версии 9.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что команда

```
export PATH=$HOME/project/bin:$PATH
```

привязана к конкретному терминалу и не прописывает этот путь в файл.
Если во втором терминале сначала набрать её, а потом как описано в вопросе

```
psql postgres
```

всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

> пришлось отдельно устанавливать psql-client версии 9.5.1.

Смотря на это плюс судя по характерному пути - вы используете Ubuntu, Debian или что-то родственное.

В общем, `psql` который вы поставили пакетом был собран с другим [`DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/include/pg_config_manual.h#L182) и потому сервер и клиент просто ищут друг друга в разных местах. Сопровождающие для Ubuntu и Debian считают что дефолтный сокет должен быть в `/var/run/postgresql/` и в том числе изменяют дефолт таким образом при сборке пакетов. Вы же дефолт не меняли.

Можно поменять аналогично `DEFAULT_PGSOCKET_DIR` и пересобрать базу, указывать `psql -h /tmp`, подключаться через TCP/IP вместо unixsock, добавить нужный путь в `unix_socket_directories` в конфигурации СУБД. Полностью на выбор.

> PSQL автоматом не появился

Не вполне представляю как этого можно было добиться не делая так намеренно и специально. Разве только может не там ищете? Должен быть там же где и `./postgres`

> psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres 
>   Ответ: psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Обратите внимание, что `initdb` по умолчанию берёт имя пользователя текущего пользователя. Имя базы `postgres` стабильно, а пользователя такого может изначально и не быть. К свежесобранной из исходников базе обычно можно подключаться как `psql postgres`

---

Довольно странная идея начинать курс по базе данных со сборки базы из исходников. При том делая форк на гитхабе - зачем вам форк? Вы собрались писать патчи для PostgreSQL? Ну я поддерживаю конечно и советом малого контрибьютора помогу. Но что меня пугает сильнее - вы ветку исходников выбрали? `master` ветка PostgreSQL - это не стабильная версия, и даже не тестируемая, а находящаяся в активной разработке. Иногда может даже собственный `make check` не проходить. Хоть это и не нормально и исправляется оперативно, но бывает и такое.

Answer (score 0):

Почему не установили из репозиториев? Там всегда есть свежие пакеты для всех ОС.
Вы экземпляр инициализировали? 
Обычно, экземпляр запускается pg_ctl start -D ~/project/DemoDb

Вот еще, для справки: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/app-pg-ctl

Comment: Делаю по инструкции из курса по базам данных в OpenEdu

Comment: Понятно...
И все таки, initdb делали?
ps ax | grep postgres - что выдаёт?
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres  - что выдаёт?


Если только начинаете, ставьте из репозиториев, не издевайтесь над собой. На официальном сайте есть инфа как подключать репозитории

Comment: 1-й терминал:
pg_ctl start -D ~/project/DemoDb Ответ: команда не найдена...
initdb делали, после него сервер и запустили описанным в вопросе способом.
ps ax | grep postgres Ответ: 5202 pts/4 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto postgres(красным).

2-ой терминал:
5252
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres Ответ: psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist

Comment: 2-ой терминал:
ps ax | grep postgres 
Ответ: 5252 pts/4    S+     0:00 ./postgres -D /home/j_ch/project/DemoDb
 5254 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process   
 5255 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process   
 5256 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process   
 5257 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process  
 5258 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process   
 5282 pts/17   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres Ответ: psql: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist